# Cannot resolve symbol 'AnnotationConfiguration' for Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle

I have been embarking on a project using Hibernate where I want to retrieve data. However, when I try configuring the `AnnotationConfiguration` like the one below,

```
try {
        factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().
                configure().
                //addPackage("com.xyz") //add package if used.
                        addAnnotatedClass(AbtDebtbbyCAN.class).
                        buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
```

I'm getting error like :

> Cannot resolve symbol 'AnnotationConfiguration'

May I know how to resolve the error? I believe the mistake lies in the Gradle configuration for Hibernate. This is how I've configured it.

**Build.Gradle**

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-gradle-plugin', version: '5.4.22.Final'
```

Note: `AbtDebtbyCAN` is an entity class

Comment: Can anybody tell me where I'm wrong? It's either Gradle or the configuration is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out the reason why it gave me an error. Basically, `“org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration”` is deprecated after the release of `Hibernate 3.6`. As a result, all its functionality has been moved to `“org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration“` and hence the code needs to be amended like this:

```
try {
        factory = new Configuration().
                configure().
                //addPackage("com.xyz") //add package if used.
                        addAnnotatedClass(AbtDebtbbyCAN.class).
                        buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
```

Hence, in this way, the program can be executed. So, to top it all up, it's got nothing to with `Gradle`, it's got to do with the compatibility of the configuration. Hope this answers the question.